# How to select first value from autocomplete google api address with press key tab textbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, google-api

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLvAg.png)

> How to select first value by click on tab from auto complete google api address textbox this is my code and also fill loaction id and location name.

```
<input type="text" id="pac-input2" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Where" />
                        <input id="place_Id4" type="hidden" />
```

> my jquery code is.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize(e) {
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input2');

    var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        debugger
        console.log('call');
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete1.getPlace();
        console.log(place.place_id);
        console.log(place.formatted_address);
        $("#place_Id4").val(place.place_id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could make a working demo with just default + autocomplete?

Comment: i attach a screen shot i want to hit tab i want to fill first text and value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to see the markup produced by the script, hence I need a working demo/fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wgzkq182/